# Extract fixed number of elements per row in numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

Suppose I have an array `a`, and a boolean array `b`, I want to extract a fixed number of elements from the valid elements in each row of `a`. The valid elements are the ones indicated by `b`.

Here is an example:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
b = np.array([[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1]]).astype(bool)
x = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    c = a[i,b[i]]
    d = np.random.choice(c, 2)
    x.append(d)
```

Here I used a for loop, which will be slow in case these arrays are big and high-dimensional. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generate a random uniform [0, 1] matrix of shape `a`.
2. Multiply this matrix by the mask `b` to set invalid elements to zero.
3. Select the `k` maximum indices from each row (simulating an unbiased random `k`-sample from only the valid elements in this row).
4. (Optional) use these indices to get the elements.

```py
a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
b = np.array([[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1]])
k = 2

r = np.random.uniform(size=a.shape)
indices = np.argpartition(-r * b, k)[:,:k]
```

To get the elements from the indices:

```
>>> indices
array([[3, 2],
       [5, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 5]])
>>> a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], indices]
array([[ 3,  2],
       [11,  7],
       [15, 14],
       [22, 23]])
```